# Not able to fetch response URL in APIGEE

Tags: apigee

Heloo 
I am trying to get the response url from  the backend. i am able to get request url, but not able to get response URL. Any suggestions/ ideas are mush appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by response URL? For the majority of requests, the URL is the target of the request, and there is no response URL. A URL may be put into the payload of the request, and there is a URL returned when the request should be redirected to another URL.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the rply. I get a different url which contains auth code. i want to fetch this code from url. So i am thinking if their is something like response.url like request.uri in apigee.

Comment: If you can post an example response you are getting from your backend (the output from cURL or some similar tool), I can probably tell you how to access the field. There is no response.url (HTTP responses don't require URLs by default -- they automatically go back to the caller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your backend sends a redirect URL (as HTTP 302 Location Header) and the URL contains an auth code that you want to extract in the Apigee proxy-flow response path -

You can use a java script policy in the Response path of your proxy flow, like below:

```
url = context.getVariable("response.headers.Location");
var re = new RegExp("#.*[?&]" + "code" + "=([^&]+)(&|$)");
var code = url.match(re);
context.setVariable("authcode", code);
```